How to color background in pyplot while having no axes
You can color the background of your subplot by using the set_facecolor command, but when also using axis(False) to remove the axes, it no longer works. To no avail, i have tried to google an answer, and for this reason i have decided to make this thread.
Here is my code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

T = np.linspace(2*np.pi, 15*np.pi, 360)
r = [k**-1 for k in T]
x = [np.cos(a) * b for a, b in zip(T,r)]
y = [np.sin(a) * b for a, b in zip(T,r)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
spiral, = ax.plot(x, y, color = "b")
radius, = ax.plot(x, y, color = "k")
dot, = ax.plot(x, y, color = "r", marker = "o")

ax.set_facecolor("black")
ax.axis(False)

def update(num, x, y, spiral, radius, dot):
    spiral.set_data(x[:num + 1], y[:num + 1])
    radius.set_data([x[num], 0], [y[num], 0])
    dot.set_data([x[num]], [y[num]])
    return spiral, radius, dot

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, len(x), interval=5, 
                              fargs=[x, y, spiral, radius, dot], blit=True)
ani.save('spiral_export.mp4', writer = "ffmpeg", fps = 60)

If it is of any relevance, it animates a rotating stick that gradually gets smaller, drawing a spiral in its endpoint.

Just draw a colored rectangle on top that covers the entire window.

Yes, i did consider doing this, however it just seems silly/weird that the set_facecolor function doesn't work, but oh well

x=np.cos(T)/T, etc
